# How to make this specific query using xslt 2.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xpath-2.0

The Below mentioned content is my XML Document.

```
<w:document>

    <w:body>
             <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para1</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para2</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para3</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading4">Para4</w:p> 

             <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para5</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para6</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading4">Para7</w:p> 

             <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para8</w:p> 
             <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para9</w:p> 

             <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para10</w:p> 


    </w:body>

</w:document>
```

So, While reading each `<w:p>`, i want to check its attribute value pStyle Value.For example, in the above file,the first `<w:p>` contains that attribute value as **"Heading1"**. So, For the first `<w:p>`, i don't care about anything and just take it.After, taken this `<w:p>`,

***Logic 1 :***i want to split the attribute value **Heading1** for retrieving strings after the **Heading**. So,Now we get **'1'**.

Afterwards, the While reading next `<w:p>`,Apply the same ***Logic 1*** for spiting the current attribute value.So,in this case, we have **'2'**. Now, i want to compare this current value **'2'** with previous value **'1'**.

***Logic 2 :*** If it is less than the previous value then only select the current `<w:p>`,otherwise,don't do anything.

Apply the above ***Logic 1 and Logic 2*** for all of the `<w:p>` nodes.

So,In my case, I want to select, only the following `<w:p>` nodes.

> Required Selection is :

```
Para1
Para5
Para8
Para10
```

Hope u understood my problem...

What i do for this situation?...

Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Thanks & Regards,
P.SARAVANAN

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for three different solutions for both XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 and also pure XPath 10/XPath 2.0 one-liner expressions that select exactly the wanted set of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just use this XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
/*/*/w:p[not(substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading')
            >= 
             substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading')
             )
         ]
```

**A corresponding XPath 2.0 expression selecting the same set of elements is**:

```
 /*/*/w:p[1]
|
 /*/*/w:p[position() ge 2]
             [xs:integer(substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading'))
            lt
              xs:integer(substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading'))
             ]
```

**If you use XSLT 2.0, you can override the [identity rule/template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) as follows**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "w:p[xs:integer(substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading'))
      ge
       xs:integer(substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading'))
       ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (fixed to be well-formed):

```
<w:document xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
    <w:body>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para1</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para2</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para3</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading4">Para4</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para5</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para6</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading4">Para7</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para8</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading3">Para9</w:p>
        <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para10</w:p>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
   <w:body>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para1</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para5</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para8</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para10</w:p>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

**The corresponding XSLT 1.0 solution with overriding the identity rule is slightly simpler due to XPath 1.0 lacking strong typing:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
        <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match=
      "w:p[substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading')
          >=
          substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading')
           ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Or, you can simply use the expressions from the start of this solution**:

XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:w="Undefined!!!" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
<w:document xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
    <w:body>
     <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/*/w:p[1]
      |
       /*/*/w:p[position() ge 2]
                 [xs:integer(substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading'))
               lt
                xs:integer(substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading'))
               ]
      "/>
    </w:body>
 </w:document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 1.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
<w:document xmlns:w="Undefined!!!">
    <w:body>
     <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/*/w:p
          [not(substring-after(@pStyle,'Heading')
              >=
               substring-after(preceding-sibling::*[1]/@pStyle,'Heading')
               )
          ]
      "/>
    </w:body>
 </w:document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**All of the above three XSLT transformations produce the wanted, correct result**.

Comment: @@Dimitre Novatchev : what are the required in case, if "Heading1"(or Heading2 or Heading3...) Attribute inside <w:p><w:pPr><w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/></w:pPr></w:p>.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done in XSLT1.0, by a simple addition to the identity transform. You just need to ignore **w:p** nodes where the **pStyle** attribute is greater than, or equal, the previous sibling, I think.

```
<xsl:template match="w:p[
       number(substring-after(@pStyle, 'Heading')) 
       &gt;= number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/@pStyle, 'Heading'))
    ]">
   <!-- Ignore the node -->
</xsl:template>
```

Here is the full transform in this case (note that you may have to amend the namespace)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://stackoverflow.com/users/452680/saravanan">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="w:p[number(substring-after(@pStyle, 'Heading')) &gt;= number(substring-after(preceding-sibling::w:p[1]/@pStyle, 'Heading'))]">
       <!-- Ignore the node -->
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied on your sample XML, the output XML is as follows:

```
<w:document xmlns:w="http://stackoverflow.com/users/452680/saravanan">
   <w:body>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para1</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para5</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading2">Para8</w:p>
      <w:p pStyle="Heading1">Para10</w:p>
   </w:body>
</w:document>
```

Comment: @ Tim C : "@*|node()" what does it refers?

Comment: That will match any attribute of the current element, and any child element. Essentially, it says copy all attributes and children of the current element.